# How to change jQuery version in magento 1.9.3.4

Tags: magento, content-management-system

I am new in magento and cms in general so my question is what are the steps to accomplish this task ? i have found solutions for  newer version. Extension that i downloaded require jQuery > 1.8 and i found out that my actual version is 1.7.2.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First on your page press CTRL + U (if chrome), than CTRL + F. type jquery, find line where ..scrip... src="...jquery.1.7.2...> (you need jquery file, not jQuery plugin or smth.) this step for find name of jquery file, becouse it can be jQuery.min.1.7.2.js jQuery.1.7.2.js and etc...)

Copy file name

Open any IDE or smth.  For load magento project files if you haven't it. Use function like Find in folder, and look for copied name. It should be in theme layouts folder or base layouts folder.

Download right jQuery version and put it where is old one.

Comment that line where xml loads old jQuery, and load new one in local.xml. 
(or just replace in that xml, but it is bad practice, better make changes in local.xml)

Comment: Thanks will try it for sure